# Adding two transformers?

Tags: transformer

I need a high turn ratio transformer in a small package. Is it feasible to put two small transformers together, as follows:

[image]

Two small turn count transformers would be smaller than a single transformer in the sizes I need.

Can I use this transformer pair somewhat equivalently as a single transformer? Anything I should look out for? Thanks!

Comment: What are you feeding into the transformer(s) and what load is on the output. Also what data do you have on the transformers?

Comment: @Andyaka I'm feeding in 4-5 volts and I'm storing the high voltage on the output in a capacitor. This way I don't need high current, my main constraint is getting a high turn count transformer in the smallest package possible. I need something less than 5mm tall and not too wide/long, preferably under 10mm.

Answer (score 2):

> Two small turn count transformers would be smaller than a single
>   transformer in the sizes I need

That's unlikely to be true for the following reason. The size of the transformer is largely dictated by the power it has to transmit through its windings and this, in turn, dictates the core size. Any ratio transformer is permitted provided there is enough room to cram-in the wires. Using two transformers to transmit (say) 1W of power means both have to be rated to pass this power and this means that they will together, occupy twice the volume of one transformer.

It's another matter if you can't get hold of a certain size transformer but there is always the option to rewind the secondary.

Here's a 100:1 step up transformer that is 6.6mm x 6.6mm: -

[image]

Do you need one smaller than this?

Comment: Thanks! I was actually planning to use those, but I need something in the 1:200 to 1:400 range, so I was thinking of using two of those in the method I described.

Comment: @user2461391 Why was your example showing a 1:100 then? That sort of lack of information is, at best, just rude.

Comment: @user2461391 as for not asking the question correctly I'll leave others to comment but from what you want to do I think there is a better solution. Now's a good time to explain what you want ie how much voltage you want to charge a cap up to.

Answer (score 0):

If you can find a 1:100 transformer but need 1:200 (or 300 or 400) but your current requirements are low, one answer is to follow the transformer with a [voltage multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier) (aka voltage doubler in its simplest form, or Cockroft-Walton multiplier).

The output impedance of these increases quickly as you add further stages, so you can't increase the voltage indefinitely this way without paying a penalty in limited output current, but you can (slowly!) charge a capacitor or provide low current HV supplies.

I stepped a 12V square wave (from a CMOS 555) up to 60V DC for a capacitor microphone bias supply, in a low noise system where I wanted to avoid inductors altogether.